# 403 Forbidden message to hide index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I added this content to my `.htaccess` to root directory. but I got 403 forbidden message!

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php53 php53 php

php_flag  log_errors on
php_flag  display_errors on
#php_value error_reporting 8
php_value error_reporting E_ALL

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^shidsa.com/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.shidsa.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA] 

</IfModule>

order allow,deny
allow from all
```

this should work fine:

http://shidsa.com/test.php

Comment: In the code shown, there is no directive causing a 403 response. There must be other directives, either in one of the .htaccess files, or in the main configuration.

Comment: when I remove it my url will work .

Comment: Maybe your script returns 403, or the PHP version 5.3 is not available on your server.

Comment: I removed `AddType application/x-httpd-php53 php53 php` and it works fine. please send your comment as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no directive directly responsible for causing a 403 response.

Possible reasons for a "Forbidden" response might be

- a script returning status code 403

  > Check the scripts return code
- PHP version 5.3 is not available or forbidden for some reason (e.g. security)

  > Change the PHP version to some current version, e.g. 5.6 or 7.0, or remove the `AddType` directive altogether